# How the value of m is 7?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I couldn't understand how the value of m=7 after execution of program.

```
void test(int m , int &n)
{
    n=n-2*m;
    m=2*m;
}


int main()
{
    int a=7, b=12;
    test(a,b);
    
   cout << a<<b;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never print the value of `m` at any point, so how do you know what its value is or isn't after execution of the program? If you're wondering why the value of `a` is still `7`, notice that `test` accepts its first argument by value and its second argument by reference and reread the section in whatever you're using to learn C++ that discussed the difference between `int` and `int&` for function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The 'm' is a local variable.So in the function'test',it is '14' right.[image]If you want change the 'a',you should use "int&m".

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering why  cout << a<<b is printing 7 for first value, it is because you did not pass first parameter to function test as reference. So any change done on the first parameter in the test function is local to the test function only and the change would not be reflected in the main function. If you pass first parameter also as reference (as you did for the second one) you would see different output.